# Grel to apply to ALL columns or current column

Tags: openrefine

I have a transposition that I'd like to apply to multiple columns.  The Grel generated shows the columnName or Base name, but that means I have to edit the code for each column.  Thought there was a way to find the column index and have code that would apply to the "current" column, a list of columns by index or all columns.

Specifically, I'd like to trim whitespaces and have 20+ columns.

Explored foreach and row.index but can't find anything like column index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately multi-column operations are not supported by the current version of Refine.

Comment: Thanks Tom. That could be a very useful feature.

Comment: Apply to GREL to multiple columns is now supported in OpenRefine 2.7

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to trim leading and trailing white space for entire projects with OpenRefine 3.2.

A standard column gets added to all projects "all". At the top of the "all" column click the <kbd>down arrow</kbd> > select "Transform", then in the Expression box enter `value.trim()` and click ok.

Next you will be allowed to select via check box the columns you would like transformed. Click ok & that should run over all selected columns for your project.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, even though it came over 5 years after the OP.